# Globalization not working in cordova 4.3.0 for android platform

Tags: android, cordova

I tried following steps:

1) cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.globalization

2) Added in config.xml:

```
<feature name="Globalization">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />
</feature>
```

3)

```
function checkLanguage() {
      navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
        function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
        function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
      );
    }
```

4) calling checkLanguage().

None of the callbacks are fired.

I really need this.

Comment: are you sure calling this function in onDeviceReady ?

Comment: Added your comment in answer and i will accept it ..thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function in onDeviceReady

> The deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. Once the event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs.